# How to Install SVN Plugin in Eclipse IDE in windows

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I have installed the Eclipse IDE and imported the project from svn server in my local system and after it I have imported the project in my Eclipse IDE.
Now I want to manage my repository by Eclipse not by System explorer.
So is there any plugin of SVN in Eclipse that can manage my repository? And if yes, how to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an plugin called 'Subclipse 4.3.3'.
To install it just follow the steps below:

Open Eclipse > In 'Help' Tab > Click on Eclipse Marketplace... > In search section Search 'Subclipse 4.3.3'

Now it will list the required plugin.
Now click on 'Install' Button and it will add the plugin in th Eclipse after taking some time.

For connecting the project with Eclipse's SVN just follow steps:
Right click on the project > click Team > Share Project... > select SVN > Then pur your SVN credential to authenticate the connection.
After above it will setup the project with SVN Eclipse plugin.

If above is not working follow this link:

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/eclipse/configuring-svn-and-eclipse/